# the product of diagonals of a regular polygon

Tags: complex-analysis

[Problem no `1.160`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310213/how-to-prove-displaystyle-frac-sin-2n1-theta-sin-theta) on my previous question.

> Let $ABCD...PQ$ represent a regular polygon of $n$ sides inscribed in a circle of unit radius. Prove that the product of the lengths of the diagonals $AC, AD, ... , AP$ is $\frac14 n \csc^2  \left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right )$.

How do I proceed? I am thinking $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n-2} \left | 1 - e^{i\frac{2\pi k }{n}} \right |$, am I in right direction? And how do I simplify it?

Comment: what is the source of the problems?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee it's Schaums Series Complex Variables ... want it??

Comment: Well, $k$ should go from $2$ to $n-2$ in that expression.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287976/the-distance-from-1-to-the-other-nth-roots-of-unity

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287691/the-roots-of-unity-and-the-diagonals-of-the-n-gon-inscribed-in-the-unit-circle

Comment: I think the answer should be $\frac{1}{4}n\csc^2 \pi/n$. For example, when $n=4$, there is one diagonal of length $2$, and $\csc \pi/4 = \sqrt 2$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes sorry .. for error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $p(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(z-e^{2\pi ik/n}\right)=1+z+z^2+... + z^{n-1}$.

Then note that the value you are looking for is:

$$\left|\frac{p(1)}
{(1-e^{2\pi i/n})(1-e^{-2\pi i/n})}\right|$$

But $p(1)=n$. And the denominator is $2-2\cos(2\pi/n)$.  But $1-\cos 2x = 2\sin^2 x$, so we get that the value you are looking for is $$\frac{n}{4\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{n}}$$

Comment: why am i looking for that form??

Comment: Form was a typo, meant "for." But you are looking for that value because $|p(1)|$ is the product of all the lengths from $AB\cdot AC\cdot AD\dots AQ$ and the denominator is dividing by the lengths that are not diagonals, $AB\cdot AQ$.

Comment: Oh!! I see .. also I understand the comment you made. I was reading improperly.