# Product of regular n-gon diagonals inscribed in unit circle = n

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The wiki for regular polygon diagonals says:

"For a regular n-gon inscribed in a unit-radius circle, the product of the distances from a given vertex to all other vertices (including adjacent vertices and vertices connected by a diagonal) equals n."

Can someone provide a basic proof?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Diagonals

Comment: See also: [Simple prove that product of the diagonals of a polygon = N](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/835278)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f = x-1$ and $g = (x^n-1)/(x-1) = 1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n-1}$. Together, $f$ and $g$ have as zeros all the vertices of the unit $n$-gon in the complex plane.

The number we are looking for is now the absolute value of the product $R$ of all terms $a-b$, where $a$ is a zero of $f$ and $b$ is a zero of $g$. This $R$ is known as the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $f$ and $g$.

This resultant is also the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of $f$ and $g$, which is constructed from the coefficients of $f$ and $g$. In this case, the Sylvester matrix has the form

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & & & 1 \\
1 & \ddots & & \vdots \\
 & \ddots & -1 & \vdots \\
& & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and thus the determinant $\pm n$. Hence $|R|= n$.