# Geometric interpretation of identity in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that if $1, z_1, z_2, \ldots,z_n$ are the $(n + 1)$th roots of $1$, then
$$(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdots (z-z_n)=1+z+z^2+\ldots +z^n.$$

Make a graphic interpretation of the situation.

I already did the main result, which was to prove that identity (factor theorem, mainly what I used), but I don't understand how to give an interpretation to that, someone could explain that part to me.

Comment: Draw the nth roots of a unit circle. z-z_n is the vector from a point outside to the point on circle

Comment: @Tryst, I don't see how that connects with $1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^n$ (but I also don't see anything better).

Comment: The equality for $z=1$ is [Simple prove that product of the diagonals of a polygon = N](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835278/simple-prove-that-product-of-the-diagonals-of-a-polygon-n).

Comment: What about something like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dzo02bchds)?